# Comparing items in a stack

Tags: java, stack, boolean

I am trying to compare two seperate stacks to see if they are the same or not. I have a loop iterate through each object in each stack and compare both objects. What I want to happen is if they are equal, continue the loop and return true. If they are not equal at any given point, break the loop and return false. This is what I have written:

```
    public boolean isPalindrome (Stack a, Stack b) {
    Object temp1;
    Object temp2;
    boolean answer;

    for (int i = 0; a.size() > 0; i++) {
        temp1 = a.pop();
        temp2 = b.pop();

        if (temp1 != temp2) {
            answer = false;
        }
        else {
            answer = true;
        }

    }
    return answer;

}
```

What I see happening in this is that I have a boolean, and through each loop that boolean is assigned a value depending on what the objects are, then at the end of the loop, return that boolean in its most recent state. No matter what I initialize the variable to, its like the loop does absolutely nothing to it. Can you not modify or return a boolean in a loop? What would be the better way to go about this instance? I have looked at tons of other posts for similar issues, but most of them seem to be trying something a little different ad I would like to stick as true to my original ideas as possible, I just need to know what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions would help greatly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea that you can `return false` (which breaks method execution) once you find stacks are not equal. Otherwise `return true`:

```
public boolean isPalindrome (Stack a, Stack b) {
    if (a.size() != b.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    while (a.size() > 0) {

        if (!a.pop().equals(b.pop())) {
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: I tried that, it returns true every time even if the objects don't equal each other

Comment: @xTopShelfx Ok, I've made a small edit, check once again

Comment: Hmm it's still not working.. I have no idea why either because everything looks like it would run fine, but it's just not picking up the return statement in the loops... and every once in a while I'll get an error saying "unreachable code"

Comment: @xTopShelfx works fine for me, please check it here http://ideone.com/h8qkbg Does you stack contain primitives or objects?

Comment: You should always compare by `a.pop().equals(b.pop())`! Otherwise you will compare the references of both objects if they are equal.

Comment: That's weird maybe there is something else in my program thats causing it.. here's the whole class http://ideone.com/plPOoC

Comment: @nikis that has your implementation in it as well

Comment: @bobbel that is why I asked what's inside the stack

Comment: I got it figured out guys, it was an issue elsewhere in my code. The stacks ultimately weren't the same size because I was popping from one stack and pushing into another, practically voiding out the first stack. I used a copy of the stack to compare them both and then all of your suggestions (as well as mine) continued to work properly. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: @xTopShelfx it's because when you call `pop`, the element is being deleted from the stack. That is why when you pass `stack` to the `isPalindrome` it's already empty and it's size is 0 => return true (while statement is not reachable). Check this example http://ideone.com/BTa7G8 to make think clear

Comment: @nikis look at my previous comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  public boolean isPalindrome (Stack a, Stack b) {
    Object temp1;
    Object temp2;
    boolean answer = true;

    for (int i = 0; a.size() > 0; i++) {
        temp1 = a.pop();
        temp2 = b.pop();

        if (temp1 != temp2) {
            answer = false;
            break;
        }

    }
    return answer;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place a `return` statement when you find a false item -- else, you're simply returning the boolean found in the last iteration of your loop.

```
public boolean isPalindrome (Stack a, Stack b) {
Object temp1;
Object temp2;
boolean answer;

for (int i = 0; a.size() > 0; i++) {
    temp1 = a.pop();
    temp2 = b.pop();

    if (temp1 != temp2) {
        answer = false;
        return answer;
    }
    else {
        answer = true;
    }

}
return answer;
```

}

Comment: I've tried it with just a return statement as well, and it was giving me errors saying that the method needs a return statement. Basically its not even registering that there is a boolean in the loop, I've tried it multiple ways....

Comment: It's important to also place a return statement **outside** the loop (and outside any if-test) to make sure that the function will always end with a return statement.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
public boolean isPalindrome (Stack a, Stack b) {
    if (a.size() != b.size()) return false;
    while (a.size() > 0) {
        if (a.pop() != b.pop()) {
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put a break statement in just after answer is set to false. Without this, you are returning false only if the last items are not equal.

Quick note: I would also add a check for the case that the two stacks are not the same size.

Comment: Oh whoops I actually did have a break in there, guess I accidentally deleted it. The stacks will always be the same size because I have a string pushed into a stack, then back again into another stack to reverse the order of it.